# Unable to uninstall a python package using pip if it was installed using -t option

Tags: python, pip

I have installed docker-compose using:

`sudo pip install docker-compose -t /usr/bin`

but now when I try to uninstall it I got the following error:

```
sudo pip uninstall docker-compose
Found existing installation: docker-compose 1.29.2
Not uninstalling docker-compose at /usr/bin, outside environment /usr
Can't uninstall 'docker-compose'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

I have tryed some work arounds such as:

`sudo pip  install --force-reinstall docker-compose --no-cache-dir`

`sudo pip install --ignore-installed docker-compose --no-cache-dir`

but they didn work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some old installation of docker-compose using apt-get was interfering with pip package database, causing the problem.

I run:

`sudo apt-get --purge autoremove docker-compose`

and then I was able to uninstall the package using:

`sudo pip uninstall docker-compose`

Comment: Had a problem where i accidently deleted my docker-compose binarary, before running pip uninstall.. which i think screwed up the uninstall process. 
But by running the first of your steps, i was able to completly remove docker-compose, which made the pip uninstall process say it was not installed.
I could then install the newest version on my Pi, which was my goal. Thanks :-)